# Why shared_variable is reset to nil in gtest

Tags: c++, c, googletest

here is my code, xmlDoc* d always be reset to nil in "ExTest, try1"

ex_test.cpp

```
typedef const char* str;
class ExTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    static str html;
    static xmlDoc *d;

    static void SetUpTestCase() {
        html = "<html></html>";
        xmlDoc *d = xmlParseDoc((const xmlChar *) html);
        d;//0x685a30
    }
};

str ExTest::html = NULL;
xmlDoc *ExTest::d = NULL;

TEST_F(ExTest, try1) {
    d; //nil
}
```

Comment: @machine_1 I invoke libxml2, it's c lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different variables, both called `d`.

```
static xmlDoc *d; <- here's one

static void SetUpTestCase() {
    html = "<html></html>";
    xmlDoc *d = ... <- here's the other
```

You probably meant:

```
    d = xmlParseDoc((const xmlChar *) html);
```

This will set the value of the existing `d` variable rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @nwaicaethi it'd be nice if you accepted this answer.